# ASP.NET MVC C# Beginner - Views and Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to ASP.NET and have a very simple question regarding C# being used in the View. I am attempting to display the current date time, but it is showing the C# code, not the datetime.now. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Controller:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyFirstHelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // GET: HelloWorld
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return View();
        }
    }
}

View:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<body>
    <div>
        This is our first MVC Application.
        The current date and time is <%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%> 
    </div>
</body>

Displays the below result:

This is our first MVC Application.
The current date and time is <%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>
```

Comment: You are using the wrong syntax for MVC try `@ViewData["CurrentTime"]` instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster Out of hammers for today? Wish I had considered that route, d'oh!

Comment: @David don't have it (yet...) for MVC :)

Comment: @Kev did you just dupehammer it _after_ the C# tag was added?

Comment: @CodeCaster - couldn't honestly say.

Answer (score 2):

It's a razor view, so replace

```
<%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>
```

with

```
@ViewData["CurrentTime"]
```

Razor syntax is prefixed with the @ sign as you can see in the title declaration, whereas aspx syntax uses the more classic <% %> style.

Comment: This question is a typo and should be closed, not answered.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: Because the question is of no benefit to any future visitors which is why SO exists.

Comment: Except for those who confuse razor with aspx. A typo is not the same as going down the wrong path syntactically in my book.

Comment: How about someone confusing C++ with C#? Would you leave that here too?

Comment: Thank you. As I am new to ASP.NET, I find this useful. I believe I was confusing razor and aspx. The tutorial I'm going off of is from 2010, so I assumed there would be some differences. I guess the 2015 version of VSx > ASP.NET MVC apps default to razor engine? Thanks again!